# terminating a process using process name

Tags: c++, winapi, terminate

I've been trying to create a program that will terminate a process using the process name. 
Upon searching, APIs CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, Process32First, OpenProcess and TerminateProcess will help me in doing this program.

But upon compiling, I got an error "error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'"
On this part "if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)"

Any suggestion on how to solve this error?

Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>
void killProcessByName(const char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                      (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            if (hProcess != NULL)
            {
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
int main()
{
    killProcessByName("calc.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion how to solve this error: go to www.google.com and search how to convert a`WCHAR *` to `const char *`. A metric ton of hits (many of them on this very own site, stackoverflow.com, how about that?). Read them.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling your project with Unicode enabled, so the `TCHAR`-based API functions you are calling will map to their Unicode versions (`Process32First()` -> `Process32FirstW()`, `Process32Next()` -> `Process32NextW()`), and thus `pEntry.szExeFile` will be a `wchar_t[]` and not a `char[]`.  But `strcmp()` takes only `char*` strings as input. That is what the compiler is complaining about, you passing a `wchar_t[]` where a `char*` is expected.

To solve this, you will have to either:

- call the ANSI version of the API functions directly, to match your ANSI `filename` parameter.

  ```
  void killProcessByName(const char *filename)
  {
      HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
      if (!hSnapShot) return;

      PROCESSENTRY32A pEntry;
      pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);

      BOOL hRes = Process32FirstA(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
      while (hRes)
      {
          if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
          {
              HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, pEntry.th32ProcessID);
              if (hProcess)
              {
                  TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                  CloseHandle(hProcess);
              }
          }
          hRes = Process32NextA(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
      }

      CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
  }

  int main()
  {
      killProcessByName("calc.exe");
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- change your `filename` parameter to `wchar_t*` to match the Unicode functions, and use `wcscmp()` instead of `strcmp()`.

  ```
  void killProcessByName(const wchar_t *filename)
  {
      HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
      if (!hSnapShot) return;

      PROCESSENTRY32W pEntry;
      pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);

      BOOL hRes = Process32FirstW(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
      while (hRes)
      {
          if (wcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
          {
              HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, pEntry.th32ProcessID);
              if (hProcess)
              {
                  TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                  CloseHandle(hProcess);
              }
          }
          hRes = Process32NextW(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
      }

      CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
  }

  int main()
  {
      killProcessByName(L"calc.exe");
      return 0;
  }
  ```